# Why can I use a collection initializer with private set access from another class?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following code:

```
public sealed class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Items = new List<OrderItem>();
    }

    public List<OrderItem> Items { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class OrderItem
{
}
```

and here's `Order` initialization in another class.

```
var order = new Order
{
    Items =
    {
        new OrderItem(),
        new OrderItem()
    }
};
```

Could you explain why it works? As you see the `Order` has `private set` property, so I thought it would be impossible to set its value.

Comment: Collection initializer does not create instance of collection. Remove `new` from constructor and you will get an exception. Add some items in constructor and they will stay after initialization in another class.

Comment: WOW, I never ever realized that this is possible with nested collections. Thank you for asking!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short answer:

It works thru [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) which calls `Add` to add items

### Long answer:

Accodingly C# 3.0 cpesification, object which implement `IEnumerable` and has appropiate `Add` method can be initialised thru the `Add` method.

`Items` has `public get` accessor and `Items` it's a `List<T>` which implements `IEnumerable` and has `Add`. Here's  how the compiler sees your code

```
var order = new Order();
order.Items.Add(new OrderItem());
order.Items.Add(new OrderItem());
```

Please note, the compiler doesn't use info that the `List` implements `IEnumerable`, here's the proof, no exception will be thrown

```
public sealed class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Items = new MyCollection();
    }

    public MyCollection Items { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class OrderItem
{
}

public class MyCollection : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly List<OrderItem> _items = new List<OrderItem>();

    public void Add(OrderItem item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

from **C# Language Specification**

> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied
>   must be of a type that implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or
>   a compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the
>   collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object with
>   the expression list of the element initializer as argument list,
>   applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, the
>   collection object must contain an applicable `Add` method for each
>   element initializer.

Comment: Strange that it needs to implement `IEnumerable` since it is not used by the collection initializer.

Comment: @Magnus: That was a controversial decision at the time. We did a broad study of types that have an `Add` method and discovered that there were two broad categories: mutable collection classes, and mathematical classes.  No one wanted to get into a situation where you could use a collection initializer to do math. The telling difference was that the collections almost all implemented `IEnumerable` and the math types did not, so we chose that as our shibboleth.

Answer (score 12):

Your statement works because the collection initialization syntax uses the `Add()` method to add the items to the collection rather than setting the member to a new instance of a collection. Essentially, your code is the equivalent of:

```
var order = new Order();
order.Items.Add(new OrderItem());
order.Items.Add(new OrderItem());
```

Which is fine since you only ever use the getter method.