# Property without setter cannot be assigned to, but other one without can

Tags: c#

I'm seeing some really strange behavior (probably something obvious I'm missing) in my C# code.

The following causes an error on the `TableName` property. "A property without setter or inaccessible setter cannot be assigned to".

```cs
public class MyEntity
    {
        public IList<MyRow> Rows { get; }

        public string TableName { get; }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity
                    {
                        Rows = { myRow },
                        TableName = "SomeString"
                    };
```

The error goes away if I add a `set;` to the `TableName` property. How come the `Rows` property doesn't need one as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I use a collection initializer with private set access from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664475/why-can-i-use-a-collection-initializer-with-private-set-access-from-another-clas)

Comment: The answers in the duplicate question says the "why" but doesn't say "how to know the why by yourself". So, let me introduce a popular tool that show you what the compiler does to your code behind the scenes. It's (https://sharplab.io).
When you put a "COMPILE-ABLE" code, you'll get the result and see by yourself that it just calls the add method and pass myRow to it. That's why it doesn't need a setter.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Youssef13. That's a really helpful way to see what's really going on here